# Get process name from pid or handle

Tags: c#, windows, process, handles

Assuming I already have the handle to a window, I can get the PID with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`. Is there a way I can get the process name without having to get all the processes and try to match my PID?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `Process.GetProcessById` to get `Process`.  `Process` has a lot of information about the running program.  `Process.ProcessName` gives you the name, `Process.MainModule.FileName` gives you the name of the executable file.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you. And I can also get other information too regarding the process.

Comment: Note that Process.MainModule.Filename fails when called on a 64bit target from an x86 program. ProcessName does not suffer from that limitation.

Comment: @EricLaw Do you know if the opposite is true?  Like when using a 64bit program to call Process.MainModule.Filename on an x86 target?

Answer (score 14):

```
string name;
using (var p = Process.GetProcessById(id)) { name = p.ProcessName; }
```

Comment: Process objects are disposable.  You need to dispose of the Process.

Comment: you are right, I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

// Here is a neat little method to return the task manager memory. If the process id doesn't exist, it will throw an exception and return 0 for the memory

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the process memory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processId">The process identifier.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <para> </para>
    /// <para> </para>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException"> </exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"> </exception>
    /// <exception cref="ComponentModel.Win32Exception"> </exception>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException"> </exception>
    /// <exception cref="PlatformNotSupportedException"> </exception>
    /// <exception cref="UnauthorizedAccessException"> </exception>
    public static long GetProcessMemory(int processId)
    {
        try
        {
            var instanceName = Process.GetProcessById(processId).ProcessName;

            using (var performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", instanceName))
            {
                return performanceCounter.RawValue / Convert.ToInt64(1024);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```